# How can I use es6 module in node.js?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I use node v5.1.1 and when I type this command:

```
node --v8-options | grep harmony
```

I can see an option called *--harmony_modules*

But when I run the code with --harmony_modules

```
'use strict';
import * as lib from 'b.js';
lib.run();
```

The error come out:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

Why would this happen?